# c++ - runtime error: vector push_back()

Tags: c++, vector, runtime, push-back

Please tell me reason why this code have runtime error.
I think that addEmployee() function is problem.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

enum EmployeeLevel {fresh, sophomore, junior, senior};

class Employee {
    string name;
    EmployeeLevel level;
public:
    Employee(const string & _name, const EmployeeLevel _level)
        : name(_name) {
        level = _level;
    }
    Employee(const Employee & employee) {
        name = employee.name;
        level = employee.level;
    }
    void changeLevel() {
        level = static_cast<EmployeeLevel> (level + 1);
    }
};

class Manager: public Employee {
    vector<Employee *> group;
public:
    Manager(const string & _name, const EmployeeLevel _level)
        : Employee(_name, _level) {}
    ~Manager() {
        for (vector<Employee *>::iterator it = group.begin(); it != group.end(); ++it)
            delete *it;
    }
    void addEmployee(Employee * employee) {
        group.push_back(employee);
    }
};

int main(void)
{
    Employee e1("홍", fresh), e2("김", sophomore), e3("차", fresh);    

    Manager m1("Tom", senior);
    m1.addEmployee(&e1);
}
```

If I modify the function(addEmployee()) as shown below, not error.
But I want to know reason why using "push_back(employee)" has runtime error.

```
void addEmployee(Employee * employee) {
    Employee * tempEmployee = new Employee(*employee);
    group.push_back(tempEmployee);
}
```

Comment: I use Dev-C++ Version 5.11

Comment: Not your problem _now_, but the default copy constructor of `Manager` will copy the _pointers_ in `group`. That's bad, because `~Manager` will then delete them - twice. Solution: `Manager(Manager const&) = delete` removes that default copy ctor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the first version, that crashes, is that you add a pointer to a *local variable*, i.e. an object that the compiler manages the storage for. That means when the `Manager` gets destructed it will try to `delete` this object, an object you haven't allocated with `new`.

Only `delete` what you `new` (and `delete[]` what you `new[]`)!

In fact, I see no reasons to have a pointer at all. Instead have a vector of plain objects, i.e. `std::vector<Employee>`.